# Como centrar y/o alinear contenido dentro de un div con CSS

Tags: html, css

No he podido lograr que un texto se alinee *horizontal y verticalmente*  dentro de un `div`.

Tengo el siguiente **css**:

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

div{
    display: grid;
        background-color: blue;
        max-height: 200px;
        min-height: 200px;
        min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    div p{

        color:white ;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>{tkn}</p>
</div>
```

En teoría el párrafo dentro del `div` debería salir centrado tanto *horizontal* como *vertical* según el código **css**, pero el texto me lo esta pintando en la parte de arriba.

Es decir que no lo esta centrando *verticalmente*, solo *horizontalmente*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los estilos del div, debes substituir el "display: grid;" por "display: flex;" y en los estilos del elemento p, debes agregar estas dos líneas:
margin: 0 auto;
align-self: center;

Comment: Display grid permite perfectamente alinear el contenido en el centro, si así lo quiere hacer él

Comment: Si es la respuesta sin embargo no es necesario que sea flexbox. El justify-content y el align-items también funcionan con grid.

Answer (score 1):

Para arreglarlo, únicamente cambia los estilos que tienes en el `p` en el parent

```
div {
    display: grid;
    background-color: blue;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Sólamente cambiando esos dos atributos del p al div ya se te centrará verticalmente el contenido del div.

Tienes que recordar que quien marca el estilo de como se verá el contenido es el contenedor, no el contenido.